# Adding 2 letter variables to create a word and cant use .strip on said word

Tags: python, strip

I'm making a person information gatherer that searches there name on Instagram, Snapchat, etc. and to do so in python I'm going to take a harder way then to create like a textbox, I'm doing it using key captures, it's like the keyboard plugin but it's just regular python code / openCV code, I'm using openCV to putText, create a frame(because I use Pycharm and it cant pickup keys without a window) and I need the cv2 waitkey so I can detect what key is pressed. The way it creates the words from the keys is it saves the previous key and current key, then adds them together like `prevKey = prevKey + CurKey` and then you get two words afterwards, because people have 2 names First and Last(well 3 but idc about the middle) and so I want to use strip to do `newWord = prevKey.strip()[0]` But when I do that it outputs the first letter of the 2 words and not the first word, I think it does that, because it thinks it is a string. Is there anyway of me to do it this way or should I start over?

The variable NW is newWord and is testing out how I can accomplish this, same thing for pk and key just experimentations.
Visit this website to get key to number spreadsheet file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ni3ru4hlegos938/Keys.xlsx/file
This is the Full code:

```
import webbrowser
import cv2
import time
word = " "
num = 1
key = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
alp = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
while True:
    success, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.putText(frame,'Type First And Last Name',(220,25),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.5,(0,127,255),1)
    cv2.putText(frame,'And Then Hit Enter',(245,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.5,(0,127,255),1)
    cv2.putText(frame,'Then Select What Sites To Search',(160,75),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.5,(0,127,255),1)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) % 256
    if k != 255:
        i = k - 97
        if i >= 0:
            letter = alp[i]
            if num == 1:
                pl = letter
                key = key+1
            if num == 2:
                word = pl + letter
                print(word)
                print(num)
                key = key+1
            if num >= 3:
                word = word + letter
                print(word)
                key = key+1
                cv2.putText(frame,word,(245,100),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.5,(0,127,255),1)
            num = num + 1
        if k == 32:
            pk = key
            key = 0
            word = word + ' '
        if k == 13:
            for idc in range(100):
                print(" ")
            print(word)
            newWord = word.strip()[pk]
            NW = word.strip()[0]
            print(pk)
            print(newWord)
            print(NW)

    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't actually what you are asking for but I think you are taking about `keylogger`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging Are you? If you are trying to create this then I can give you other/better idea to do this!

Comment: It's for python and its using the cv2.waitKey to capture keys, I can spell the full name ex: John Stone, but I cant use .strip so I can separate the first and last, that is what the experimental code was for / is for

Comment: Do you know what is `.strip` and why it is used? https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp check here to know about strip

Comment: This is terribly unclear. Aro you asking how to reduce a name down to just initials? `strip` is the wrong function for that, you want `split` and extract the first character from each resulting substring: `initials = ''.join(x[0] for x in name.split())`

Comment: ... And if that's your question, it can be reduced to just two or three lines of code; see the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question right, you want to get the first word of a string, in this case the first name of a name. Like this:

```
>>> John Doe
John
```

What strip does is remove whitespace from the two ends of a string:

```
>>> "       whitespace is blank  characters like  spaces      ".strip()
"whitespace is blank  characters like  spaces"
```

What you are looking for is probably str.split:

```
>>> "Three word sentence".split()
["Three", "word", "sentence"]
```

It returns a list of the words in their initial order. So, you can use it like this:

```
>>> "John Doe".split()[0]
"John"
>>> "John Doe".split()[1]
"Doe"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are taking about `split` function not `strip` function. Just changing `strip` into `spilt` should solve your problem.

Comment: yea probably thanks